# Connection to MySQL Server via MySQL Workbench errors

Tags: mysql, ssh, connection, valentina-studio

So I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using MySQL workbench. Now I have successfully connected using Valentina Studio. Keep in mind I am using MacOS Sierra.

I get the error: 
Error opening SSH connection to server (username@xxx.xxx.xx.xx)
Could not establish SSH connection: Error reading SSH protocol banner

In MySQL workbench I have it set up like so: 
Under Parameters: 
Hostname: xxx.xxx.xx.xx 
port: 1433
Username: my username
Password: my password

then under Remote Management:
Hostname: xxx.xxx.xx.xx
port: 1433
Username: my username
Password: my password

If I don't set it up this way then it never reaches SQL editor page. It gives me the error mention above and says No Connection. How can I fix this, an why did I not have an issue connecting with Valentina Studio?